# How to make a data table recognize functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, function

I found a function online somewhere that is able to execute string equations. For example I can have a string such as "1+5". When I pass it to the function, it returns returns the answer. In my application, I am pulling formulas from a database and replacing unknown numbers (such as x, y, or z) with actual numbers (1,2,3,4,5 etc) inputed by the user when they use the application. However, some of the formulas I need to execute need square roots. When I try to pass a string that contains the Math.Sqrt() function it gives me an error saying that it is an un-definded function. Is there a way I can modify the function to recognize this function?

The function uses a data table. Here is the code:

```
public static double executeFormula(string expression)
{
    System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("expression", string.Empty.GetType(), expression);
    System.Data.DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    table.Rows.Add(row);
    return double.Parse((string)row["expression"]);
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: what exactly are you using 'from online somewhere'?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. If you mean where did I get it, I got it from a forum like this answering a question about the ability to parse string equations.

If you're asking what I'm using it for, it's for a project I have at school. We need to parse a formula that is pulled from a database.

Comment: Instead of `string.Empty.GetType()` you can write `typeof(string)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [nCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) and be done with it.

It supports exactly what you are talking about and it's extensible for those things you haven't hit yet.

Comment: @dash: It is.  We use it to solve two main problems.  The first to run some complicated math functions that aren't known until runtime.  The second is that we used it to implement a simple rules engine for page processing.  Very Very easy to use and pretty darn quick to boot.

Comment: Awesome. Best library ever! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the answer is no, as you've written it. The function you are showing is exploiting a feature of DataColumn's in data tables, the [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) property.

Effectively, it supports many of the operators you'd find in SQL:

From the documentation:

```
OPERATORS

Concatenation is allowed using Boolean AND, OR, and NOT operators. You can use parentheses to group clauses and force precedence. The AND operator has precedence over other operators. For example:

(LastName = 'Smith' OR LastName = 'Jones') AND FirstName = 'John'

When creating comparison expressions, the following operators are allowed:

<

>

<=

>=

<>

=

IN

LIKE

The following arithmetic operators are also supported in expressions:

+ (addition)

- (subtraction)

* (multiplication)

/ (division)

% (modulus)

STRING OPERATORS

To concatenate a string, use the + character. Whether string comparisons are case-sensitive or not is determined by the value of the DataSet class's CaseSensitive property. However, you can override that value with the DataTable class's CaseSensitive property.

WILDCARD CHARACTERS

Both the * and % can be used interchangeably for wildcards in a LIKE comparison. If the string in a LIKE clause contains a * or %, those characters should be escaped in brackets ([]). If a bracket is in the clause, the bracket characters should be escaped in brackets (for example [[] or []]). A wildcard is allowed at the beginning and end of a pattern, or at the end of a pattern, or at the beginning of a pattern. For example:

"ItemName LIKE '*product*'"

"ItemName LIKE '*product'"

"ItemName LIKE 'product*'"

Wildcards are not allowed in the middle of a string. For example, 'te*xt' is not allowed.

PARENT/CHILD RELATION REFERENCING

A parent table may be referenced in an expression by prepending the column name with Parent. For example, the Parent.Price references the parent table's column named Price.

A column in a child table may be referenced in an expression by prepending the column name with Child. However, because child relationships may return multiple rows, you must include the reference to the child column in an aggregate function. For example, Sum(Child.Price) would return the sum of the column named Price in the child table.

If a table has more than one child, the syntax is: Child(RelationName). For example, if a table has two child tables named Customers and Orders, and the DataRelation object is named Customers2Orders, the reference would be:

Avg(Child(Customers2Orders).Quantity)

AGGREGATES

The following aggregate types are supported:

Sum (Sum)

Avg (Average)

Min (Minimum)

Max (Maximum)

Count (Count)

StDev (Statistical standard deviation)

Var (Statistical variance).

Aggregates are usually performed along relationships. Create an aggregate expression by using one of the functions listed above and a child table column as detailed in PARENT/CHILD RELATION REFERENCING above. For example:

Avg(Child.Price)

Avg(Child(Orders2Details).Price)
```

Unfortunately, Square Root is not one of the functions you can use. However, as you are using a DataTable, you can simply loop through the rows, and calculate the SquareRoot directly from the column value. Imagine you had a column called "MyNumber". You could then do something like:

```
myDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { Name = "MySquareRoot", DataType = typeof(Double)});

foreach(DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
{
  myDataTable["MySquareRoot"] = Math.Sqrt(Convert.ToDouble(myDataTable["MyNumber"]));
}
```

You could put this sort of function into an [Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) method if you wanted to.

Alternatively, you might want to handle your formulas somewhere else; rather than use a DataTable to model your data, you could use a class. The class itself could have properties (or a list or collection) that represents your data, and methods that act on your data - you can then use any function you want in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can create "Text Functions" that people will be able to recognize and use, and that you can parse in your program. Take a look at [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) or [MS Math 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15702). For instance you can do something like the following:

```
if(str.IndexOf("sqrt")>-1)
{
    //replace sqrt for the actual Math.Sqrt() function
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the CodePlex project [flee](http://flee.codeplex.com/). Flee allows you to evaluate string expressions such as `"sqrt(a^2 + b^2)"` at runtime.